# Call javascript function inside table cell

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a javascript function which returns true or false, indicating whether or not an IBAN number is valid.

I would like to call this function inside a cell i have in a repeater, which is bound to data from a database.

The evaluation of 'strCustomfield4' contains the IBAN string, which I would like to provide as a parameter, when calling the isValidIBAN() function.

```
        <asp:Repeater runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("strDeliveryName") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("strCustomfield4") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        isValidIBAN('SomeIban');
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

How can I set the returned value of the function as the innerHTML of the cell?

Comment: why do you want to process this on the client side?  When binding data to your repeater you're processing data on the server.  Your `isValidIBAN` function could be a C# function in your code behind on the `ItemDataBound` event of the repeater.

Comment: I am forced to do so, as I am using a function in a remote .js file.
http://www.tbg5-finance.org/checkiban.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript to trigger the validation. so you can assign a class an ID to this specific cell ( if it is the only cell with IBAN which you wanna validate) or you can write loop over the table cells and check them one by one. an example would be:

```
       <asp:Repeater runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("strDeliveryName") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("strCustomfield4") %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="validateIBAN">
                        323432asdfasdf <!-- IBAN -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and in JS **Assuming that you're using JQUERY**, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".validateIBAN").each(function(){
         isValidIBAN($(this).html());
         // do whatever validation you want inside $(this).html("VALIDATION OUTPUT")
   });

}
```

**EDIT:**
Changed the JS function and included it in .ready(), so it can be called automatically after page load.
See this example, if prompts an alert if the IBAN is correct. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DSh4b/1/)

Comment: this is assuming he's using jQuery.

Comment: This looks promising. I am using JQUERY, however it doesnt seem like the validateIBAN function is being called.

Currently, as a test, I only have alert("Hello?"); inside the function, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Tsanas I updated the answer with a demo, check it, and update me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `JavaScript` function you can call a server side method or you can validate the value in `ItemDataBound` of a `Repeater`, which will be called after every repeater item bounded.